# C# Infix to Postfix convertor not giving the right answer if few case

Tags: c#, postfix-notation, infix-notation, shunting-yard

I made a `Infix` to `Postfix` convertor, and thought it worked, but when I went back and showed it to my teacher one of the examples he tested turns out wrong. :|

I would be grateful if someone could help me on this matter, and let me know what's wrong.

I skipped the parts about the buttons for inputting numbers and only posted the rest of it,

```
    private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string infix = textBox1.Text;
            infixTopostfix obj = new infixTopostfix(infix);
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is the Postfix of  {1}", obj.createPrifex(), infix);

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The part above is for redirecting a `console.writeline` to my text box and its the button that does all the works and gives the final result.

Here is the main class:

```
class infixTopostfix
{
    public infixTopostfix(string strTemp)
    {
        strInput = strTemp;
    }

    private int isOperand(char chrTemp)
    {
        char[] op = new char[6] { '*', '/', '+', '-', '^', '(' };
        foreach (char chr in op)
            if (chr == chrTemp)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        return 0;
    }
    private int isOperator(char chrTemp)
    {
        char[] op = new char[5] { '*', '/', '+', '-', '^' };
        foreach (char chr in op)
            if (chr == chrTemp)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        return 0;
    }

    private string strResualt = null;
    private string strInput = null;
    public string createPrifex()
    {
        int intCheck = 0;
        //int intStackCount = 0;
        object objStck = null;
        for (int intNextToken = 0; intNextToken <= strInput.Length - 1; intNextToken++)
        {
            intCheck = isOperand(strInput[intNextToken]);
            if (intCheck == 1)
                stkOperatore.Push(strInput[intNextToken]);
            else
                if (strInput[intNextToken] == ')')
                {
                    int c = stkOperatore.Count;
                    for (int intStackCount = 0; intStackCount <= c - 1; intStackCount++)
                    {
                        objStck = stkOperatore.Pop();
                        intCheck = isOperator(char.Parse(objStck.ToString()));
                        if (intCheck == 1)
                        {
                            strResualt += objStck.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    strResualt += strInput[intNextToken];

        }//end of for(int intNextToken...)
        int intCount = stkOperatore.Count;
        if (intCount > 0)
        {
            int c = stkOperatore.Count;
            for (int intStackCount = 0; intStackCount <= c - 1; intStackCount++)
            {
                objStck = stkOperatore.Pop();
                intCheck = isOperator(char.Parse(objStck.ToString()));
                if (intCheck == 1)
                {
                    strResualt += Convert.ToString(objStck);
                }
            }
        }

        return strResualt;
    }

    private System.Collections.Stack stkOperatore = new System.Collections.Stack();

}
```

}

Here is the input that fails:

> A^B^(C-D/(E+F))-(G+H)^L*Z+Y

the result of this code which is incorrect:

> ABCDEF+/-^^GH+-LZY+*^

The correct result:

> ABCDEF+/-^^GH+L^Z*-Y+

Comment: lol i Googled Shunting yard algorithm , it seems u are right ! judging by wikipedia , i am trying to convert  an infix to postfix using that algorithm,  anyway , i think my problem lie at the priority of operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) to postfix notation, AKA [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), one must take into account [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and [operator associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). These are usually implemented as a table and looked up in the table based on the operator character.

e.g.
[Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)
[C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
[C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

As I do not see any mention of precedence or associativity in your code; so I would say your code does not have a bug but an invalid algorithm.

The classic algorithm to convert infix to postfix is the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) by [Edsger Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Dijkstra) and is probably the means closest to what you are trying to implement.

I would suggest that you work with pen an paper to understand the shunting algorithm then implement the algorithm using many test cases that progressively use more combinations of the operators.

The best explanation I know of is [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm#shunting_yard)

If you Google for C# shunting yard you will find many implementations, just make sure if you use one it is correct. Many people like to post examples of this but often have a mistake. Verify they work against many test cases before you waste time with them.

Comment: Great , Tnx for the References examples and explanation :D i will check them up and try to either fix or rebuild my code using them :D

Comment: Sorry bro , i am new here and dunno how things work and i think i can't upvote u coz i don't have 15 Reputation :| not sure how u get reputation either .

Comment: well when i click Upvote it say i need At least 15 Rep to do a Upvote !  but i can accept it , Tnx :D